# race condition in FileScanRDD.scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to create a DataSet from a single CSV file :
     val ss: SparkSession = ....

```
 val ddr = ss.read.option("path", path)
 var df = ddr.option("sep", ",")
          .option("quote", "\"")
          .option("escape", "\"") // want to retain backslashes (\) ...
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .option("comment", "#")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("format", "csv")
           ddr.csv(path)
```

df.count() returns 2 times the number of lines in the CSV file.

There appears to be a problem in FileScanRDD.compute.
I am using spark version 2.0.1 with scala 2.11. I am not going to include the entire contents of FileScanRDD.scala here.

In FileScanRDD.compute there is the following:

```
 private[this] val files = split.asInstanceOf[FilePartition].files.toIterator
```

If i put a breakpoint in either FileScanRDD.compute or FIleScanRDD.nextIterator the resulting dataset has the correct number of rows.

Moreover, the code in FileScanRDD.scala is:

```
private def nextIterator(): Boolean = {
        updateBytesReadWithFileSize()
        if (files.hasNext) {
          currentFile = files.next()
          ....
        }
        else { .... }
....
}
```

if i put a breakpoint on the files.hasNext line all is well; however, if i put a breakpoint on the files.next() line the code will fail when i continue because the files iterator has become empty. Disabling the breakpoint winds up creating a Dataset with each line of the csv file duplicated.

So it appears that multiple threads are using the files iterator or the underling split value (an RDDPartition) and timing wise on my system 2 workers wind up processing the same file, with the resulting DataSet having 2 copies of each of the input lines.

This code is not active when parsing an XML file.

I couldn't find any questions about this.
Do i have do something to prevent this behavior?

Comment: This is probably best handled via the Apache Spark JIRA. I recommend opening a new bug report there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK

Comment: Also, do you have a standalone reproduction of this issue?